# how to create a Circular Navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I copied the code from a codepen sample but my styles not affected !

**[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/juslwk/pen/xgbDB)**:

I cannot find out what is the problem!
my code:

```js
(function() {

  var button = document.getElementById('cn-button'),
    wrapper = document.getElementById('cn-wrapper');

  //open and close menu when the button is clicked
  var open = false;
  button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

  function handler() {
    if (!open) {
      this.innerHTML = "Close";
      classie.add(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
    } else {
      this.innerHTML = "Menu";
      classie.remove(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
    }
    open = !open;
  }

  function closeWrapper() {
    classie.remove(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
  }

})();
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {

  'use strict';

  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }

})(window);
// EventListener | @jon_neal | //github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener
!window.addEventListener && window.Element && (function() {
  function addToPrototype(name, method) {
    Window.prototype[name] = HTMLDocument.prototype[name] = Element.prototype[name] = method;
  }

  var registry = [];

  addToPrototype("addEventListener", function(type, listener) {
    var target = this;

    registry.unshift({
      __listener: function(event) {
        event.currentTarget = target;
        event.pageX = event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        event.pageY = event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        event.preventDefault = function() {
          event.returnValue = false
        };
        event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
        event.stopPropagation = function() {
          event.cancelBubble = true
        };
        event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
        event.target = event.srcElement || target;
        event.timeStamp = +new Date;

        listener.call(target, event);
      },
      listener: listener,
      target: target,
      type: type
    });

    this.attachEvent("on" + type, registry[0].__listener);
  });

  addToPrototype("removeEventListener", function(type, listener) {
    for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
      if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == type && registry[index].listener == listener) {
        return this.detachEvent("on" + type, registry.splice(index, 1)[0].__listener);
      }
    }
  });

  addToPrototype("dispatchEvent", function(eventObject) {
    try {
      return this.fireEvent("on" + eventObject.type, eventObject);
    } catch (error) {
      for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
        if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == eventObject.type) {
          registry[index].call(this, eventObject);
        }
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #52be7f;
  color: #fff;
}

.component {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 15em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.component>h2 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12em;
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: default;
}

.cn-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 11;
  margin-top: -2.25em;
  margin-left: -2.25em;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 4.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #52be7f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: -13em;
  margin-left: -13.5em;
  width: 27em;
  height: 27em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  transform: scale(0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*cover to prevent extra space of anchors from being clickable*/

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 6.2em;
  height: 6.2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.1em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3.1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  color: transparent;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav {
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  margin-left: -10em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.25em;
  bottom: -7.25em;
  display: block;
  width: 14.5em;
  height: 14.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #429a67;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 2;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a span {
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  display: block;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
  transition: all .3s ease .3s;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(62deg);
  transform: skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10em auto;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #6F325C;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-button {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .no-csstransforms li {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    line-height: 4em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .no-ccstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    padding: .5em;
  }
  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 4em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    font-size: .68em;
  }
  .cn-button {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:420px) {
  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="component">
      <h2>Hi</h2>
      <!-- Start Nav Structure -->
      <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">Menu</button>
      <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span>Home</span>
              <svg class="caticon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="35px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
                                    <path fill="white" id="shop-3-icon" d="M79.792,217.25v235h352.75v-235H79.792z M397.542,381.75h-282.75v-129.5h282.75V381.75z M220.62,59.75
                                                  l-17.798,85.332h-0.081v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161s-33.16-14.847-33.16-33.161v-17.34l50.841-85.332H220.62z
                                                  M168.232,59.75l-51.91,85.332v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161S50,180.736,50,162.422v-17.34l83.666-85.332H168.232z
                                                  M462,145.082v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161s-33.161-14.847-33.161-33.161v-17.34l-51.91-85.332h34.566L462,145.082z
                                                  M289.08,145.082h0.081v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161s-33.161-14.847-33.161-33.161v-17.34h0.081l16.729-85.332
                                                  h32.703L289.08,145.082z M324.739,59.75l50.841,85.332v17.34c0,18.314-14.846,33.161-33.16,33.161s-33.161-14.847-33.161-33.161
                                                  v-17.34h-0.081L291.38,59.75H324.739z" />
                                </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Furniture</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Transport</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Gift</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Clothes</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Games</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Stationary</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Toys</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Books</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Register</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Sell</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Nav Structure -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might want to change the title, I think is kind of misleading for googlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy codes from such websites, you should check for automatically added libraries. For codepen, You can do it by gear sign at the beginning of each tab.

For your particular case, see pen settings for HTML tab. There is a library link in "Stuff for header" section.

I copied it to [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/514nqvsL/1/) and it works fine.

I just added those lines

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to connect external libraries and frameworks.

```js
(function() {

  var button = document.getElementById('cn-button'),
    wrapper = document.getElementById('cn-wrapper');

  //open and close menu when the button is clicked
  var open = false;
  button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

  function handler() {
    if (!open) {
      this.innerHTML = "Close";
      classie.add(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
    } else {
      this.innerHTML = "Menu";
      classie.remove(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
    }
    open = !open;
  }

  function closeWrapper() {
    classie.remove(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
  }

})();
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {

  'use strict';

  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }

})(window);
// EventListener | @jon_neal | //github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener
!window.addEventListener && window.Element && (function() {
  function addToPrototype(name, method) {
    Window.prototype[name] = HTMLDocument.prototype[name] = Element.prototype[name] = method;
  }

  var registry = [];

  addToPrototype("addEventListener", function(type, listener) {
    var target = this;

    registry.unshift({
      __listener: function(event) {
        event.currentTarget = target;
        event.pageX = event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        event.pageY = event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        event.preventDefault = function() {
          event.returnValue = false
        };
        event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
        event.stopPropagation = function() {
          event.cancelBubble = true
        };
        event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
        event.target = event.srcElement || target;
        event.timeStamp = +new Date;

        listener.call(target, event);
      },
      listener: listener,
      target: target,
      type: type
    });

    this.attachEvent("on" + type, registry[0].__listener);
  });

  addToPrototype("removeEventListener", function(type, listener) {
    for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
      if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == type && registry[index].listener == listener) {
        return this.detachEvent("on" + type, registry.splice(index, 1)[0].__listener);
      }
    }
  });

  addToPrototype("dispatchEvent", function(eventObject) {
    try {
      return this.fireEvent("on" + eventObject.type, eventObject);
    } catch (error) {
      for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
        if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == eventObject.type) {
          registry[index].call(this, eventObject);
        }
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #52be7f;
  color: #fff;
}

.component {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  height: 15em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.component>h2 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12em;
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: default;
}

.cn-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 11;
  margin-top: -2.25em;
  margin-left: -2.25em;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 4.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #52be7f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: -13em;
  margin-left: -13.5em;
  width: 27em;
  height: 27em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  transform: scale(0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*cover to prevent extra space of anchors from being clickable*/

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 6.2em;
  height: 6.2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.1em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3.1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  color: transparent;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav {
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  margin-left: -10em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.25em;
  bottom: -7.25em;
  display: block;
  width: 14.5em;
  height: 14.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #429a67;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 2;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a span {
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  display: block;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
  transition: all .3s ease .3s;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(62deg);
  transform: skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10em auto;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #6F325C;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-button {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .no-csstransforms li {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    line-height: 4em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .no-ccstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    padding: .5em;
  }
  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 4em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    font-size: .68em;
  }
  .cn-button {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:420px) {
  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="component">
    <h2>Hi</h2>
    <!-- Start Nav Structure -->
    <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">Menu</button>
    <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Home</span>
            <svg class="caticon" x="0px" y="0px" width="35px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve">
              <path id="shop-3-icon" 
                    fill="white" 
                    d="M79.792,217.25v235h352.75v-235H79.792z M397.542,381.75h-282.75v-129.5h282.75V381.75z 
                    M220.62,59.75 l-17.798,85.332h-0.081v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161s-33.16-14.847-33.16-33.161v-17.34l50.841-85.332H220.62z 
                    M168.232,59.75l-51.91,85.332v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161S50,180.736,50,162.422v-17.34l83.666-85.332H168.232z 
                    M462,145.082v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161s-33.161-14.847-33.161-33.161v-17.34l-51.91-85.332h34.566L462,145.082z 
                    M289.08,145.082h0.081v17.34c0,18.314-14.847,33.161-33.161,33.161s-33.161-14.847-33.161-33.161v-17.34h0.081l16.729-85.332 h32.703L289.08,145.082z 
                    M324.739,59.75l50.841,85.332v17.34c0,18.314-14.846,33.161-33.16,33.161s-33.161-14.847-33.161-33.161 v-17.34h-0.081L291.38,59.75H324.739z" />
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Furniture</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Transport</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Gift</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Clothes</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Games</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Stationary</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Toys</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Books</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Register</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Sell</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Nav Structure -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```